# Is possible to know when an event starts to be listened?

Tags: events, qooxdoo

I have an object and I want to know when someone started to listen to it.

In my case there is a "click" event in my class which is a wrapper for a canvas element. How might I attach the event to the canvas when someone is listening to the wrapper?

thanks (:

([crosspost](http://qooxdoo.678.n2.nabble.com/Is-possible-to-know-when-an-event-starts-to-be-listened-tp7581945.html) because only 3 views and no reply yet)

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite addListener() in you wrapper to call your code everytime it is called.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure what do you intend to do. There is canvas element for which you can listen to it's events. Once it's fired in there, you can fire "click" in your wrapper class. You don't need to know exact listeners registered.